# jquery UI Slider value depending on active radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

I have a jQuery UI slider that goes from 0 to 200 in increments of 10.
The value of the slider appears in a box. So far, so easy.

Now I have 3 radio buttons next to my slider, labeled "full", "half", and "quarter". The "full" button is selected by default.

I want the value that the slider displays take the selected radio button value into account, so that when "full" is selected, a slider on the position of 80 displays 80, but when "half" button is active, the slider at the same position should result in the value 40 in the output text. etc.

The value output has to update not only when the slider is moved, but also when the radio button status change.

Sadly I haven't figured out yet how to use the active radio button value inside the slider value calculation. I also don't know how to trigger the recalculation when the radio button changes. Can anyone help?

EDIT: As requested here is what little code I have

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#slider").slider({
            value: 42,
            min: 0,
            max: 200,
            step: 10,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val("$" + ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider").slider("value"));
    });
</script>
```

This is basically just the example from the jQuery UI website.

The html is:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="factor" value="1"> 1 Processor<br>
        <input type="radio" name="factor" value="2"> 2 Processors<br>
        <input type="radio" name="factor" value="4"> 4 Processors
    </form>
</div>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div>
    Time needed: <input type="text" id="amount" readonly>
</div>
```

I simplified this example. The real website will have Different Models of Laser/Plasma Cutters listed with the basic model having the time factor 1 and the faster ones with values up to 6.3

Edit #2:
I have managed to get the slider to factor in the value of the active radio button like this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#slider").slider({
            value: 40,
            min: 0,
            max: 200,
            step: 10,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                var divisor = $('input:radio[name=factor]:checked').val();
                $("#amount").val(ui.value/divisor + " minutes");
            }
        });
        var divisor = $('input:radio[name=factor]:checked').val();
        $("#amount").val(($("#slider").slider("value"))/divisor + " minutes");
    });
</script>
```

I haven't figured out how to directly change the output value when the radio button is changed. Right now it only recalculates the value when the slider is moved.

Comment: You should show us what you tried so far, or at least the JS code you are using and the HTML elements involved in that.

Comment: Thank you. I have added more informationen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/351/

```
var slider;
$(document).ready(function () {
    slider = $('.checked').slider({
        max: 200,
        min: 0,
        step: 10,
        value: 200,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $('.i[value="' + ui.value + '"]:first').attr('checked', true).change();
        }
    });
    $('.i').change(function () {
        var checked = $('.i:checked').val();
        slider.slider('value', checked);
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="checked"></div>Full
<input type="radio" value="200" class="i" checked="true" name="a" />Half
<input type="radio" value="100" class="i" name="a" />Quarter
<input type="radio" value="50" class="i" name="a" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but sadly this doesn't really do what I want. Your solution moves the slider around, where as I need the slider to stay where it is and just modify the output text depending on the selected radio button.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick. First script is for when the slider moves, the second one updates the value if the radio button changes.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#slider").slider({
            value: 40,
            min: 0,
            max: 200,
            step: 10,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                var divisor = $('input:radio[name=factor]:checked').val();
                $("#amount").val(ui.value/divisor + " minutes");
            }
        });
        var divisor = $('input:radio[name=factor]:checked').val();
        $("#amount").val(($("#slider").slider("value"))/divisor + " minutes");
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=radio][name=factor]').change(function () {
            var divisor = $('input:radio[name=factor]:checked').val();
            $("#amount").val(($("#slider").slider("value")) / divisor + " minutes");
        });
    });
</script>
```